# What does the command gcloud docker -a do?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

```
$ gcloud docker -a
```

This command is ran when a Google Compute Engine instance with a `container-vm` OS and a container set to [start at instance creation time](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms#creating_containers_at_time_of_instance_creation).

Neither

```
gcloud --help
```

nor

```
docker --help
```

have the `-a` command line argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`gcloud docker` doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker) does have a `-a` option:

```
--authorize-only, -a
```

> Configure docker authorization only, do not launch the docker command-line.